# Django channels can't connect

Tags: django, redis, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have problem using channels.

They work well with localhost connection but don't work with my wifi ip address connection.

But HTTP request works well with my wifi ip connection.

Redis Server is opend at ip 0.0.0.0

Drf server is opend at 0:8080

With python redis module, both of localhost and my wifi ip connection are available.

Settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('my_wifi_ip_address', 1280)],
        },
    },
}
```

With this code, localhost connection is available but connection with my_wifi_ip_address is not available

I'm saying

```
ws://127.0.0.01:8080/ws/chat/
```

this works

```
ws://my_wifi_ip_address/ws/chat/
```

this does not work

Thanks for your help

Comment: i'm assuming you did include the port when trying to access over the network.
`ws://my_wifi_ip_address/ws/chat/` -> `ws://my_wifi_ip_address:8080/ws/chat/`. Also can you include in your message the command your using to run django?

Comment: @MatthausWoolard Thanks for you comment.  The problem was in WebSocketKing which i used to test my server. I guess WebSocketKing does not support ws(http) connection that is not localhost ip address.

Comment: yes any web-based websocket testing website will struggle to support (non https) based websocket connections that are not from local host (this is due to security restrictions but in place by the browsers) if your testing from an iPhone or iPad take a look at https://cleora.app as a testing client.

Comment: @Matthaus Woolard Thank you for your comment!!